# How to change axis and label colors?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have the following code where I want to read a text file from some location on my computer, in this case it's the desktop. It makes a plot and that is ok enough, but I'd like to change the color of the x, y axis labels as well as the title. I'd also like to add some space between the x & y axes labels and the chart axes, just so it's a bit more readable.

I've tried a number of things....nothing works, and I really have no idea why. Could someone take a look and give some insight to these please?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


filename = r"C:\Users\my_name\Desktop\my_text_file.txt"

with open(filename) as file:
    entries = [x.split(",") for x in file.readlines()]  # Read the text, splitting on comma.
    entries = [(x[0], int(x[1])) for x in entries]  # Turn the numbers into ints.
    entries.sort(key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)  # Sort by y-values.


x_coords = [x[0] for x in entries]
y_coords = [x[1] for x in entries]

plt.xticks(rotation=90)

plt.bar(x_coords, y_coords)  # Draw a bar chart
plt.tight_layout()    # Make room for the names at the bottom


# The next two lines adjust the space around the top, bottom, left & right around the plot
plt.plot()
plt.subplots_adjust(left=0.1, right=0.9, top=0.9, bottom=0.4)

plt.xlabel('The Names', fontsize=15)
plt.ylabel('Frequency of Visits', fontsize=12)

plt.title('Title', fontsize=15)
plt.subplots_adjust(top=0.85)

plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`plt.xlabel()` and `plt.title()` accept a `color=...` argument to set the color. With `plt.xlabel(..., labelpad=10)` you can adjust the padding between the label and the ticklabels. `labelpad`is measured in `points`, which is the same unit as in which font sizes are expressed (e.g. a `12 point` font). The corresponding padding for the title is simply called `pad=`.

Note that if you call `plt.tight_layout()` at the end, the calls to `subplots_adjust` aren't necessary (their values are simply overridden by `plt.tight_layout()`).

```py
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import random

xcoords = ['Nigeria', 'Ethiopia', 'Egypt', 'DR Congo', 'Tanzania', 'South Africa', 'Kenya', 'Uganda',
           'Algeria', 'Sudan', 'Morocco', 'Angola', 'Mozambique', 'Ghana', 'Madagascar']
ycoords = [random.randint(1, 10000) for _ in xcoords]
plt.bar(xcoords, ycoords)
plt.xticks(rotation=90)

plt.xlabel('The Names', fontsize=15, color='turquoise', labelpad=10)
plt.ylabel('Frequency of Visits', fontsize=12, color='limegreen', labelpad=15)

plt.title('Title', fontsize=15, color='purple')
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image: example plot]

PS: You can also change the color of the tick labels, for example `plt.xticks(rotation=90, color='crimson')`.

Also [`tick_params()`](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.tick_params.html) might be helpful to change many properties of the ticks.

Comment: Maybe your system runs a old version of matplotlib?  `import matplotlib; print(matplotlib.__version__)` outputs `3.3.1` for the current version

Comment: JohanC ---- Thank you......I tried to incorporate the label and title code into my program code, but there is no change at all. That is partly why I am confused because I looked up and tried the color-code you have suggested and it didn't work either. Nothing changes at all by adding the color and pad info you included, do you have any idea what's going on there?

Comment: JohanC --- That command throws up an error: "NameError: name 'matplotlib' is not defined". Maybe I'm not using it correctly? I tried it in the console window, and I added it to my program code and it gives roughly the same output -- not defined. I'm using Pycharm, latest version and I open it every day and let it update. I did look in Settings and it shows the version as 3.2.2 and what you indicated is an update. I'll try and update to that and see how it goes.

Comment: Ok, I DID do the update, shut Pycharm down, and restarted and re-ran the program and now it is working as desired. I can change the color and so on. I would have never thought that could/would be an issue, but I geratly appreciate that JohanC!!